# Call to a member function exec_SELECTquery() on null

Tags: typo3-9.x

I upgraded my website to TYPO3 9.5.x but I get errors with somes custom extensions after upgrade.

```
(1/1) Error : Call to a member function exec_SELECTquery() on null` in /var/www/example.com/typo3conf/ext/customext/pi1/class.tx_extension_pi1.php line 499
```

I therefore went to see in the file, and this is what I find in line 499:

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery($select, $table, $where, $groupBy, $orderBy, $limit);`
```

Comment: If you are not able or willing to change the code (like me, got that problem with a 3rd party extension) you can use this extension:  https://packagist.org/packages/friendsoftypo3/typo3db-legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no TYPO3_DB anymore, they're using a new approach. Check this topic, it might be helpful: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Migration/Index.html

UPD. It really depends on what is stored in the variables. As a basic example you can try:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
$queryBuilder->select($select)
->from($table)
->where($where)
->groupBy($groupBy)
->orderBy($orderBy)
->setMaxResults($limit);

// (optional) You can see the built SQL and try to adapt if needed
//  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($queryBuilder->getSQL());

$res = $queryBuilder->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, please can you provide more details how to convert this  `$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery($select, $table, $where, $groupBy, $orderBy, $limit);` from TYPO3 7x to TYPO3 9x

Comment: @User-110484 I have updated the answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works like that : 

`$res = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
  $res->setRestrictions(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendRestrictionContainer::class));
  $res->select($select)
     ->from($table)
     ->where(
     $where
  )
   ->execute()
   ->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 1):

Install extension [*TYPO3_DB compatibility layer for TYPO3 v9.x*/`typo3db_legacy`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/typo3db_legacy/) to provide `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` for TYPO3 9+ versions.